# How to start a recyclerview from below the toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar and a recyclerview to show notification list when clicked on the badge on tool bar.but my recyclerview is overlapping the toolbar. I need the recycler to start below the toolbar so the user can close it by touching the badge again.how can I solve this problem, can anyone help out?

**LAYOUT_FILE.xml**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dd_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toollbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/navigation_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_parent"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlNotificLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listView_Notific_Link"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#c4c3bf"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:divider="#c4c3bf"
            android:dividerHeight="7dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Give android:layout_marginTop="<height_of_your_navigation_actionbar>" to Relativelayout with  android:id="@+id/rlNotificLayout"

Comment: hey, thanks,tried that already.i have a slide down animation.so it won't look good sliding over the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should use constraint layout: [check out documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nefty workaround on that. Set a top margin on your recyclerview. Use the `layout_marginTop` property and set it to `?actionBarSize`. It should begin its layout below the toolbar.

Comment: Note that you have to include the `?` on the value. `layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"`. I'm not sure on the casing of the values but android studio should give you suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

inside your recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Try putting  layout to the top. Topmost layout goes bottom.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dd_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toollbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlNotificLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/listView_Notific_Link"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#c4c3bf"
                android:divider="#c4c3bf"
                android:dividerHeight="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/navigation_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_parent"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/drawer_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SlidingUpPanel layout.
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel